# TestFlight trouble updating provisioning profile for distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I am having a hard time updating my provisioning profile for distribution using TestFlight. I have searched many places and I assume it is due to the ios8 change.

I read in the TestFlight Q&A: App developers will now need to rebuild their Ad Hoc beta apps to update the embedded provisioning profile in the app's IPA file.

I am still in the process of slowly learning coding so I would really appreciate if somebody can help me step by step on how to embed the provisioning profile on my existing Xcode build.

Comment: what do you mean code?

Comment: All I am asking is basically what changes I need to do on my existing build in order to use testflight again. haha

Comment: @GJK Apologies for misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 8, Apple has integrated TestFlight beta testing into iTunes Connect; it is no longer a third-party service with [Apple's acquisition of Burstly, the service's parent company](http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/21/rumor-testflight-owner-burstly-is-being-acquired-by-apple/).

This has taken provisioning profiles mostly out of the picture and greatly simplified public beta testing.

All you have to do is go to your Prerelease tab under your app in "My Apps" in iTunes Connect:

[image: Prerelease]

Then, turn on TestFlight Beta Testing next to the version you'd like to test:

[image: TestFlight Beta Testing]

Finally, invite external testers from the tab located in the same menu as the "Builds" tab:

[image: External Testers]

You'll then be able to release builds to up to 1000 external testers, but you'll have to get your first build approved for testing with each new version number. However, this testing is nowhere near as intensive as the App Store review process, and in my experience the longest time it has taken is two days.

After the first build is approved, all other builds in that version are exempt from testing unless you wish to have them tested by Apple before distribution to beta testers. Each build is available to testers for 30 days from *its release* to testers (**not** when the testers themselves *start* testing them).

Testers can download new builds and provide feedback right from the TestFlight app, which is [available on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8) for iOS 8.0+.

You can find more information [here](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/downloads/Documentation/TestFlight-v09-iTC-Export-sw.mov).